# Android EditText textwatcher getting called on Screen Rotation

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an activity with simple login page in it. On click of submit button i m setting an red border on email edit text and adding a textwatcher so that on textchanged listner i can change email edit text border from red to gray. Everything works fine untill i dont change my screen orientations. when i am in potrait mode, I set red border on email edit text it gets change when i rotate the screen seem textwacther getting called. How to preserve the state of editext so that if i set its border color red it should be set as red irrespective of screen rotation also ontextchanged it should be change back to gray.

below is my Actvity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.email)
    EditText email;
    @BindView(R.id.password)
    EditText password;
    @BindView(R.id.submit)
    Button submit;
    private MyViewModel myViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        setUpTextWatcher(email,password);

        myViewModel.setError().observe(this,getErrorObserver());
        myViewModel.resetError().observe(this,getResetObserver());
    }

    private Observer<EditText> getResetObserver() {
        return  new Observer<EditText>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable EditText editText) {
                if(editText.getId() == email.getId()){
                    email.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.input_shape));
                }else{
                    password.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.input_shape));
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private Observer<EditText> getErrorObserver() {
        return  new Observer<EditText>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable EditText editText) {
                if(editText.getId() == email.getId()){
                    email.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_input_shape));
                }else{
                    password.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_input_shape));
                }

            }
        };
    }


    @OnClick(R.id.submit)
    public void autenticate(){
        myViewModel.setError().setValue(email);
    }

    private void setUpTextWatcher(EditText ...editTexts) {
        for(final EditText editText: editTexts){
            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        if(editText.hasFocus()){
                            myViewModel.resetError().setValue(email);

                        }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

below is Myview model class

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyViewModel  extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<EditText> setErrorOnEditText;
    private MutableLiveData<EditText> resetErrorOnEditText;

    public MutableLiveData<EditText> setError() {
        if (setErrorOnEditText == null) {
            setErrorOnEditText = new MutableLiveData<EditText>();
        }
        return setErrorOnEditText;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<EditText> resetError() {
        if (resetErrorOnEditText == null) {
            resetErrorOnEditText = new MutableLiveData<EditText>();
        }
        return resetErrorOnEditText;
    }
}
```

below is my xml file for setting edit text background gray:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="2dip"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"
        />
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:centerX="35%"
        android:centerColor="#fff"
        android:startColor="#fff"
        android:endColor="#fff"
        android:type="linear"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="250dp"
        android:height="50dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/input_border"
        />
</shape>
```

below is my xml file for setting edit text background red:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="2dip"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"
        />
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:centerX="35%"
        android:centerColor="#fff"
        android:startColor="#fff"
        android:endColor="#fff"
        android:type="linear"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="250dp"
        android:height="50dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/theme_color"
        />
</shape>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state)

Comment: nope i am using live data to preserve the state why i need Save instance for that ?

Comment: i think its issue with focus/cursor or textwatcher on edit text. Live data is getting called setting border to red but somehow on screen change textwatcher is also get called hence reset the state

Comment: I'm not sure about your specific problem but consider using data binding, it is so much cleaner